# Is GNU make extension to shell?

Tags: shell, make, gnu

GNU make and makefile syntax resemble Linux shell and bash, but is not the same. For example, usage of bracet is not the same as in shell or bash.

Yet, many other commands from shell can be used AS-IS, for example: echo, cd and more.

Is it correct to view GNU Make as interpreter above shell ?

Comment: If you build a tool like `make` whose purpose is to issue various commands to simplify the building of large software packages, then the obvious paradigm to use is one that is also designed to issue complex commands, and is very familiar already to all your prospective users.

Comment: resemble in what way? The fact that Make expands variables with `$(foo)`, which looks a bit like the shell's `${foo}`, or the fact that Make is used to run actual shell commands, meaning that you can use any of the shell's syntax in a makefile?

Answer (score 1):

Once you get to the command portion it's very similar.

The format for a Makefile is:

- Target (binaries)
- Prerequisites (dependencies/libs)
- Command (script)

While some Makefiles vary in appearance/format slightly (Makefile.am vs package.mk etc) they all generally follow this format.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it correct to view GNU Make as an extension to Linux shell?

This depends on how you define the term "extension to the shell".

You might define that any program that adds functionality to the shell is an "extension to the shell".

In this case every command-line-based program would be an "extension to the shell".

However, if you want to know if Makefiles can be seen as "improved shell scripts", the answer is surely "no":

Although the commands inside the rules of Makefiles are shell commands (just like the lines of shell scripts), a Makefile is used completely differently than a shell script.

And (at least in 99% of all cases) a valid Makefile is not a valid shell script and vice versa.

You might write a Makefile that acts like a shell script; however, this would make no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Make is not a shell extension. It's a separate program that does different stuff than a shell, and whose syntax happens to be similar to a shell (for consistence purposes).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) and [GNU Make's homepage](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/):

> Make is a build automation tool that automatically builds executable programs and libraries from source code by reading files called Makefiles which specify how to derive the target program.

> GNU Make is a tool which controls the generation of executables and other non-source files of a program from the program's source files. Make gets its knowledge of how to build your program from a file called the makefile, which lists each of the non-source files and how to compute it from other files.

Comment: Make does a whole lot more, if you provide your own extra rules. The man page says "You can use it to describe any task where some files must be updated automatically from others whenever the others change." I once got stuck with merging seven asset and operational databases for an electrical network company, and converting all geographic coordinates into simple schematics (like the London Underground Map). That ended up as a make that reacted to changes in 100 data files and 60 awk scripts.